# How to let know to Google Analytics that my user is still online?

Tags: google-analytics

We have a dashboard application that shows some realtime data. Usually use case is that user open some dashboard and let it opened several hours and looks at it during the time. Data on the dashboard are updated on the background. Google Analytics doesn't know that the dashboard page is still opened and results about realtime online users in GA are bad.
How to let know to Google Analytics that the user is still online?

I think about using GA events, but I do not know if it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can know it with a margin of 5 minutes:

**Active users** are those who have sent a hit to Analytics within the last five minutes.

**Active users per page** is the number of users who have sent their most recent hit from that page.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638637?hl=en